# Team members not contributing

Tags: teamwork

I work as a software developer. I have taken on another task which is not part of my job, setting up a bunch of new servers for a new application that the company I work for has bought.

I am working with two people who work full time in this area. We are supposedly working on this task as a team but the other two members are doing as little as possible. One person is remote, and we have a group skype chat. He is supposed to be doing stuff at the remote site, and he doesn't do anything. When I ask him about stuff in the group chat he either says 'sure', and then does nothing or he doesn't reply.

The other team member doesn't really have the skills required to do the job, and doesn't seem interested in learning them either.

It's frustrating. I don't really know what to do.

How can I make sure my other team members contribute to the project?

Comment: I feel with you. But what is your precise question? Also, did you contact your manager about it?

Comment: I have similar problems every now and again. I tend to give them an acceptable amount of time to complete their task then if nothings happened escalate it to a chat that has a manager in it. I try to avoid doing it until it is about become a problem for my own work. It's not your job to ride someone to complete their work. You can get the manager to do it.

Comment: Ideally you should inspire them somehow. If you can't, do all the work and take all the credit.

Comment: "I have taken on another task which is not part of my job"  Don't do that.

Comment: Can you easily accomplish this task by yourself? Tell management that you don't want those two Bozos anywhere near "your" project.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I make sure my other team members contribute to the project?

It appears you are attempting to lead this project.

If that's the case, call a meeting (via phone or whatever communication method you use for these sorts of projects), assign tasks and assign due dates. Send around notes after the meeting with the details, and include the manager(s) of each member of the project team.

Make sure that one of the tasks is another meeting to check in on the status of assigned tasks.

If this fails to keep the project on track, you may need to include the manager(s) in a meeting.

Sometimes, you'll learn that your project is not considered a priority by the other team members and that they are being instructed to spend their time elsewhere at this project's expense. The about process should help determine if that's the case. And if so, you'll need to adjust your expectations accordingly.

If you aren't actually the leader, then you simply need to escalate the issue to whoever is in the lead and ask how you can get the other team members' cooperation.